# Using only part of a class from a different target

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I just created a new target for the Lite version of my app. The Lite app only uses part of a base class that I have in the main app, ie it won't need to use an option that requires it to import 4 or 5 files.

My question is, from a design perspective, what is the best way to handle this so that my Lite version can only use the part of the class that it needs? Obviously, one solution is I just import those 4 unnecessary files into Lite build phase, and just use the whole class (even the parts it doesn't need). This seems inefficient though. I know I can do an ifndef to block those files from being imported if the Lite version is running, but how do I block out the code in the class from also not being picked up by the compiler?

Would a better way just be to have my Lite version create a subclass of the Base class that only uses the options it needs? But then I believe, would I still need to import those unnecessary files?

Just a bit confused about this, first time I've ever created another target that utilizes code from the main target. Any help appreciate thanks.

Comment: `#if` will stop code from being compiled. It can become a bit messy though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the common/lite functionality in a super class. Heavy functionality in the sub-class.

Answer (score 1):

As another answer points out, you can handle this by putting the lite functionality in a subclass and the full functionality in a superclass.

Another option is to use a single class, and add the full functionality in an Objective-C category. Essentially, you can define methods in the category to supplement – or replace – methods in the base implementation.

Unlike a subclass, however, methods defined in a category can't invoke `super` to get the base class's functionality. `super` still refers to the base class's superclass, whether that's NSObject, UIDocument, or what have you – not the implementation without the category.

The advantage is that you only have one class name, so the code which instantiates your class (or classes) doesn't need to use something like `#ifdef` to switch classes and #includes depending on whether you're building the lite or full version.